# How to check is jpeg-image in buffer is not truncated?

Tags: c++, validation, jpeg

The video-supervision system consists of three parts:

client-streamer (c++) -> server (c++) -> client-supervisor (browser/js/websockets)

Streamer sends jpeg frames from webcam to server, and server stores this frame in `std::string` buffer of this Streamer (`map<string, string>Streamers` -> `Streamers[ID].Camera`). When supervisor queries for stream of some agent, server sends back to him encoded `Streamers[ID].Camera` as binary (according to websocket standart). And resulting image blinks in browser! I think that server responds with a frame that is writing simultaneously with the agent's posting request, and this frame is sending to the supervisor truncated. Here is a screenshot:
[image: Truncated jpeg]
If to disconect client, server will send his last frame to supervisor, and this last frame is always full. It means that there is no problem with sends and receives. I almost sure that the problem is in simultaneous access to the one variable from two threads.

**So I want to add some check of the frame** on server before to send it to supervisor. Something like:

```
while(!FrameIsFull(CameraFrame)){
    Sleep(1);
}
SendAllData(Socket, websocket_encode(CameraFrame));
```

**What sould I do in this `bool FrameIsFull(string jpeg_frame)`;?**

*PS: also the FireFox often writes in console that "image is corrupt or truncated" and displays only a part of frame. How does it checks the image?*

Comment: Are you sure you're not just doing network I/O wrong? Are you expecting a single `write`/`send` call to guarantee delivery of _all_ the bytes you give it? That's not necessarily the case. Show your [MCVE].

Comment: No, sends and receives are made in custom SendAll-RecvAll functions. I did a test writes to disk on incoming frame - its always full

Comment: Disks and networks are two very different things, and just testing it doesn't mean it's correct for all circumstances. We should see this `SendAll` function.

Comment: I understand, thats why I perform this test on server after receiving an image. You can see in screenshot that there is no truncated frames on sender side, and server writes data into variable only after receiving it all. And after that I see a test image on disk

Comment: Right, and I'm trying to help you avoid the root cause, because to me this looks like a very common mistake with network I/O code. But if you don't want my help, that's fine too! Good luck.

Comment: Maybe there is some info about correct size in image header? How to analize it?

Comment: You don't need to. TCP guarantees delivery, if you use it properly. Currently, you don't seem to be using it properly, but you refuse to show the potentially problematic code. So, I cannot help further.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, sorry for my stubbornness and thank you for clarifying about the TCP guaranted delivery - it maked me to see a problem from other side. So... server's RecvAll function performs recv by chunks of 1024 bytes - the function worked correct, but it did not have time to receive all package before client sends next. It happened after I deleted a response to Client after receiving whole package to increase an exchange speed and to avoid some bugs... But is adds new bugs ))). So the chunk size was increased to 20*KILOBYTE and the image stops to blink in browser.